# Re-use value from oracle sequence in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter

I need to retrieve a value from this query

```
$result = $this->db->query("SELECT MY_SEQ.NEXTVAL VALUE DUAL") ->result_array();
```

The variable $result is used to make 3 subsequent inserts,
but everytime i need to use $result[0]['VALUE'], it will add +1 to the final value.

How could i re-use the value without use a insert and a query to get the current value of the sequence?

Ps: i am using codeigniter and a oracle 9i database

thanks in advance

Comment: Accessing the `$result` var can't possibly increase the value. Re-executing the query does that.

Comment: In fact, it should be like this, but i did a test, stored the value in a variable and made 1 insert, it worked, when i added a 2nd insert immediatelly below, the table field was increasing by 2 everytime, somehow codeigniter is re-executing the query.

Comment: There *was* a bug in CodeIgniter 2 where queries to oracle were actually executed twice, but 2.x is officially unsupported now, so I hope you're not using it still ... Unless that's the case, I'd look for triggers that try to emulate MySQL's `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: In fact i am using codeigniter 2.x since it is a legacy system, so i will try move my project for a 3.x version, thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

Once you have issued a call to nextval you can use

```
$result = $this->db->query("SELECT MY_SEQ.CURRVAL VALUE FROM DUAL") ->result_array();
```

This gives you the current value of the sequence however if other sessions are calling this sequence at the same time then you might not get a consistent result.

Comment: This is the problem, there will be at least 10 users at same time processing informations, i would not like to take this risk